# Twilio - PHP API Trouble

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I was wondering if someone can help me implement the Twilio PHP API.  I installed the library using composer and changed everything it said to in the documentation.

However, When I try to run the application I just get a blank page.  After doing some commenting, it looks like the issue is with the arrays.  When I comment out the arrays it will at least give me an error and there will be something when I check the source code.

Below is the code that I'm using.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$AccountSid = "MySid";
$AuthToken = "MyToken";
$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$people = array(
    "Number 1" => "Carlos",
    "Number 2" => "Jon",
    "Number 3" => "Madison"
);
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
    $sms = $client->account->messages->create(
        $number
        array(
            'from' => 'My Number',
            'body' => " This is a test"
            )
    );
  echo "Sent message to $name";
```

}
?>

Comment: Now that I think about it, it could be a connection issue.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't connect.

Comment: What was the error you were getting?

Comment: Blank page in PHP means there's an error sitting in your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a comma after the first argument of the `create` method.

```
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
    $sms = $client->account->messages->create(
        $number,
        array(
            'from' => 'My Number',
            'body' => " This is a test"
            )
    );
  echo "Sent message to $name";
}
```